# Embedding code within an image

Tags: java, c++, png, jpeg

Is there a way to embed executable code within an image? For example, if I have an image file (jpeg, png, etc) on my desktop, I would like to click on that image and have some embedded source code (Java, c++, etc) run in the background. Is this possible?

Comment: What for? Sounds like a virus...

Comment: You could embed something in the image, but you'd need to use another program to extract and execute that.

Answer (score 3):

No. That would constitute one terrible security hole.

That said, there are numerous "image" formats that may contain executable code. PostScript files are one famous example, and nothing's preventing you from embedding some JavaScript into an SVG file for instance. Whether it's run or not is another story. And (hopefully) none of those have complete access to your system in the manner that Java/C++/friends do.

Comment: Surely embedding C++ code in the image would not do any harm unless it's also compiled on the target system [Yes, I know, that's not what the orginal question IMPLIED, but it's what the words actually mean!]

Comment: @Mats: Well, his question also made it clear that this code (compiled or not) would be run whenever the user tries to open the image, so I guess we should assume it's compatible with the target system.